# Custom String Split Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, split

I am trying to split characters in a string which contains alphabets made out of special characters. The Idea is to split the characters in the most logical manner.
E.g. if the word is **"Football"** it can be written as **F{}{}tball**. The ideal setting should be that it is split as 'F','{}','{}'... but if I try to split it using each character then it will split like 'F','{','}'....Also there is the issue that **'}{'** also looks like an **H**, which is also a character and **'{'** also looks like a C.
I have thought about defining a Dictionary for these kinds of symbolic alphabets but it does not solve the core problem. Any advice is appreciated. 
i am working on Python and need theses characters as part of string analysis.

Comment: [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) is likely what you need. If that is not powerful enough, you might consider any of the many parsing libraries.

Comment: How will you decide how to split something like `OCH` represented as `{}{}{`?

Comment: @wwii: In a case where multiple possible splits are possible, you likely need to generate these multiple splits, interpret them, and then filter out the varaint(s) that make sense. If I understand your subject area correctly, some inputs may not have a unique interpretation, at least, not when taken out of context (which is a different problem). This will likely take a custom parser capable of generating multiple outputs, using some lookahead and trying to apply several interpretations.

Comment: .. ahh, comment was for OP but I concur with your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)) to split your string according special characters(strings).

For example:

```
s = 'F{}{}tball, G()al'

import re

split_chars = ['{}', '()']

print([ch for ch in re.split('(' + '|'.join(re.escape(ch) for ch in split_chars) + '|.)', s) if ch])
```

Prints:

```
['F', '{}', '{}', 't', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l', ',', ' ', 'G', '()', 'a', 'l']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your first step is likely to define your allowable character replacements.  Your next problem is to write a parser that can convert any sequence of special characters into the various possible translations, which is not a deterministic process.  After that step, you need to compare the resulting "words" with your acceptable lexicon to figure out what word was intended by the special characters.

There are a lot of solutions floating around for doing this translation on digit strings, with a=1, b=2, ... z=26.  With this problem, `121` can parse as `aba`, `av`, or `la`.  You can take their principles and apply those to your problem.  The general idea is to use a bit of dynamic programming and backtracking to handle the ambiguities you'll have in the formal grammar.

When I've done something this restricted, I've done it with a translation dict and recursion on the remaining string to walk through the input; if I work down to the empty string, I have a valid translation; if I get stuck before then, I return failure and let the backtracking look for the next option.  You could also do the equivalent with a state transition graph.

Comment: Can you please share some of the solutions you mentioned?